# Is it possible to have a datatable that uses more than one plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want a data table that does the following but all on the same table:

**1)** Searchable

**2)** Able to perform bulk options by using a checkbox next to rows then 'deleting all checked'for example

**3)** Sortable by clicking on the columns

**4)** Data downloadable from table into csv

**5)** Add more rows

**6)** Responsive

I seem to be able to find examples of all these features and example tables on jsfiddle but not altogether on one table. Is it possible to do this by adding all the relevant plugins to one html table?

Comment: except 5 all are possible. i did not work with 5 so, try it once , that may work

Comment: You could try? :) There is only a few rare examples where two dataTables plugins not are working together, because they manipulate the DOM in "reverse directions", but 1,3,4 and 6 is right out of the box, 2 and 5 need programming from your side anyway (not plugin dependent).